# Monotouch.Dialog ImageLoader

Tags: monotouch.dialog

Monotouch 5.2.11 Eval Version (testing it out)

On the simulator whatever images I am trying to load I get this error:

```
Error fetching picture for [url to image] to....
Problem with [url to image] System.Net.WebException: The request timed out
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00046] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:824 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x0000e] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:836 
  at MonoTouch.Dialog.Utilities.ImageLoader.Download (System.Uri uri, System.String target) [0x00038]
```

The [url to image] works fine, I can actually type in the url on the simulator browser and it loads.. I've downloaded the Monotouch.Dialog project and increased the request timeout to 100000 which doesn't seem to do much.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting this error when I had a nested dialog based on some json responses.  There were about 1000 photos and the imageloader was trying to load them all.  I thought it was only called when clicked which was not the case.   It seems the downloads were flooding the system with too many requests.

I fixed this by reusing 1 UIViewController to display the last nested level (it had the photo on it).